# Function not counting SOME number's binary gaps

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a function that will count a number's binary gap. My function seems to be working with some numbers and not with others and logically I don't understand why this code would not be working. Usually without a debugger I would Console.WriteLine and play around until I find an issue but I am not too familiar with codility and can't find a debugger or way to console write lines. Where is my logic going wrong?

I've tried moving around the if statements or using do/while instead but nothing seems to count the binary gaps for 1041.

```
 public int solution(int N) 
    {
         string binary = Convert.ToString(N, 2);
         List<int> ListOfInts = new List<int>();

        for(int i = 0; i<binary.Length; i++)
        {
         int count = 0;
            if((binary[i] == 0) && (binary[i-1] == 1))
            {
                count++;
            }
            if((binary[i] == 0) && (binary[i-1] == 0))
            {
                count++;
            }
            if((binary[i] == 1) &&(binary[i-1]==0) && (count > 1))
            {
                ListOfInts.Add(count);
            }
            else
            ListOfInts.Add(count);
        }
        return ListOfInts.Max();
    }
```

Here is my test output - 1041 should be returning the 5 I have stored in the list from a count int.

```
Compilation successful.

Example test:    1041 
WRONG ANSWER  (got 0 expected 5) 

Example test:    15 
OK 

Example test:    32 
OK
```

Comment: `Usually without a debugger I would Console.WriteLine and play around until I find an issue but I am not too familiar with codility and can't find a debugger or way to console write lines` Copy the code into a console app on your local machine (or on dotnetfiddle) and try your `Console.WriteLine` approach.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't even think about this after getting too bogged down behind the logic.

Comment: A few suggestions:
`binary` is a string, so you probably want to do character comparisons rather than integer comparisons. Ex. `if(binary[i] == '0')`
You seem to be resetting count on each loop interation. You probably only want to reset it when you reach a '1'

Comment: Kyle you're so right thank you! I had actually tried comparing to chars before but it wasn't working because I was overlooking my incorrect reset on the count. Problem solved! Thanks so much for all of your help!